# jQuery .attr() changing video height not working properly

Tags: jquery, video, resize, height, attr

I've been facing a problem for days which drives me crazy!

when i try to set attributes "width","height" of video tag in html file, it just works fine.. but when i try to change attr by jQuery, it won't work!

for example:

Case 1 (without jQuery):

css:

```
#VID_CON{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    height:100%; /* height equals to 662px*/
    float:left;
    background-color:green;

}
```

html:

```
<div id="VID_CON">
  <video id="MYVID"  width="100%" height="400px" >
    <source src="media/tm.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

will look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw9A3.jpg)

Case 2 (with jQuery):

css:

```
#VID_CON{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    height:100%; /* height equals to 662px */
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="VID_CON">
  <video id="MYVID"  width="100%" height="400px" >
    <source src="media/tm.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

   var vid_h= $("#VID_CON").height(); //returns "662"
       $("#MYVID").attr("height", vid_h +"px") ;   

},200);
```

Now it will look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wjMo.jpg)

So, what am I missing here? Please help..

Best regards.

Comment: Your element `<div id="VID_CON"></div>` has a height determined by it's content (the video). You must set its size from CSS or, via jQuery, based on some other element that is NOT inside `<div id="VID_CON"></div>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just solved the problem..

```
window.setInterval(function(){

   var vid_h= $("#VID_CON").height(); //returns "662"

       //#mep_0 is the id of MediaElement video container
       $("#mep_0").css("height", vid_h +"px");
       $("#MYVID").attr("height", vid_h +"px");  

},200);
```